# Kinect - Depth stream + video stream into DirectX11 texture

Tags: c++, direct3d, kinect, directx-11

I am following the Kinect SDK tutorials and it seems to be working fine so far.

The problem I have is that it uses DirectX9 for the rendering and I wish to use DirectX11 instead.

I managed to get the actual depth and video streams into BYTE * but I need a way to convert it into a DirectX11 texture.

Has anyone done something similar to what I am trying to do? If you have some sample code it would help me a lot thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using DirectX11 for uploading kinect data is pretty straightforward.

There is an example [here](http://hieroglyph3.codeplex.com/)

Roughly on another simple way you can create your texture with dynamic usage flag, and then use map/unmap function to copy the stream data to gpu.

here is a little [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff476905%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) about it.